# Recreating WebViews while changing the orientation in android

Tags: android, android-orientation

I have built an application and the best part is, it is running fine and the worst part is,whenever I hold the device and turn it from portrait to landscape or vice versa,the views are regenerating each and every time when the orientation changes.I have done all the possible things to the best of my knowledge i.e.

1.created `layout-land` folder and placed the xml file for the landscape mode.
   2.Have given the following permission in the manifest:

```
 android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"
```

Is there anything else I have missed out?

I do not want the changes or recreation to occur whenever I change the orientation.

Comment: remove "layour-land" folder and keep "android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden", check what happen

Comment: @AndroidCoader-I have a separate xml file for `layout-land` for the landscape and need to keep that in order to fit the screen for the landscape mode.

Comment: If you have separate xml for landscape mode why you are setting android:configChanges in manifest as Oncreate will not be called when you switch to landscape mode. By setting android:configChanges you telling android system to avoid creating activity again, So any changes required should be handled manually .

Answer (score 1):

By default,Android activity is recreated when orientation is changed, and xml layout used by default is xml that you have in "layout" folder unless you have a separate xml in "layout-land" for landscape mode.

On the other hand if you want to handle Orientation or any other config changes by you self and to avoid calling OnCreate() then use "android:configChanges" in manifest file and Overide OnConfigChanges in your activity.

Answer (score 0):

The reason that it is recreating your views is because the oncreate is being called. This will ideally reset all your views. If you override the method that handles the orientation changes, you will catch it a lot easier and preserve your views.

Ex:
http://jnastase.alner.net/archive/2010/10/27/handling-orientation-change-in-android.aspx